# Appropriate OAuth2 flow for JavaScript API client

Tags: javascript, api, oauth

Reading the latest OAuth2 draft, I'm unsure which flow is appropriate for the client I'm developing -- or whether OAuth is appropriate at all.  The data served from our API isn't specific to a user; having credentials simply grants a user access to our data.

The JS client I'm building will be a public page that doesn't require the user to authenticate.  Instead, the "user" is the JS client itself.  That is, there's a special account just for this app to access our API.

Currently I'm simply adding an `Authorization` header with HTTP Basic credentials, which is bad for many reasons.  Most of all, anyone could very easily extract the username and password.

The closest match I see in the OAuth draft for this scenario is the Implicit Authorization Grant, but it still seems like the person operating the user-agent (web browser) would have to interact with the page to get an access token.  Having to, say, click a button, and then go round trip to the auth server and then back to the JS client (through the `redirect_uri`) isn't appropriate.

On the other hand, without being able to use a private key (because it's JS), I can't imagine how the client could be verified without using the `redirect_uri`.

Can someone set me straight?

Comment: This looks like a case for simple cookies. Create a one-off key that you hand to each client, expire it in a few hours (and renew as needed while on page).

Answer (score 0):

The access token is passed to your redirect_uri in the url fragment. You can obtain it by parsing the window.location.hash value.

> On the other hand, without being able to use a private key (because it's JS), I can't imagine how the client could be verified without using the redirect_uri.

The implicit grant type does NOT authenticate the client. In some cases, the client identity can be verified via the redirct_uri used to deliver the access token to the client. It relies on the presence of the resource owner (its credential) and the registration of the redirection URI. redirect_uri is required in this flow. Some SDKs say that it's "optional" because they have a default configuration which is usually the same domain where the API service resides, or it's pre-configured on the resource provider.